# select query to fetch rows corresponding to all values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider this example table "Table1".

```
Col1   Col2
 A      1
 B      1
 A      4
 A      5
 A      3
 A      2
 D      1
 B      2
 C      3
 B      4
```

I am trying to fetch those values from Col1 which corresponds to all values (in this case, 1,2,3,4,5). Here the result of the query should return 'A' as none of the others have all values 1,2,3,4,5 in Col2.

Note that the values in Col2 are decided by other parameters in the query and they will always return some numeric values. Out of those values the query needs to fetch values from Col1 corresponding to all in Col2. The values in Col2 could be 11,12,1,2,3,4 for instance (meaning not necessarily in sequence).

I have tried the following select query:

```
select distinct Col1 from Table1 where Col1 in (1,2,3,4,5);

select distinct Col1 from Table1 where Col1 exists (select distinct Col2 from Table1);
```

and its different variations. But the problem is that I need to apply an 'and' for Col2 not an 'or'.

like Return a value from Col1 where Col2 'contains' all values between 1 and 5.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use analytic **ROW_NUMBER()** function.

**[SQL FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91c29/1)** for a setup and working demonstration.

```
SELECT col1
FROM
  (SELECT col1,
    col2,
    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) rn
  FROM your_table
  WHERE col2 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
  )
WHERE rn =5;
```

---

**UPDATE** As requested by OP, some explanation about how the query works.

The inner sub-query gives you the following resultset:

```
SQL> SELECT col1,
  2    col2,
  3    row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) rn
  4  FROM t
  5  WHERE col2 IN (1,2,3,4,5);

C       COL2         RN
- ---------- ----------
A          1          1
A          2          2
A          3          3
A          4          4
A          5          5
B          1          1
B          2          2
B          4          3
C          3          1
D          1          1

10 rows selected.
```

`PARTITION BY` clause will group each sets of col1, and `ORDER BY` will sort col2 in each group set of col1. Thus the sub-query gives you the row_number for each row in an ordered way. now you know that you only need those rows where row_number is **at least 5**. So, in the outer query all you need ot do is `WHERE rn =5` to filter the rows.

Comment: This works. I'm gonna try to check for all scenarios. Also, would you mind elaborating about the query? I have not used OVER or PARTITION query parameters before.

Comment: @Hemang It is analytic function. `PARTITION BY` clause will group each sets of col1, and `ORDER BY` will sort col2 in each group set of col1. Thus the sub-query gives you the row_number for each row in an ordered way. See the update will explanation.

Comment: Ok great. Got it. Yes I was just checking it with my extended query including other parameters, so in case of any queries/errors I can consult you before accepting. Def will accept now. Thanks for the solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use listagg function, like

```
SELECT Col1
FROM
(select Col1,listagg(Col2,',')  within group (order by Col2) Col2List  from Table1
group by Col1)
WHERE Col2List = '1,2,3,4,5'
```

Comment: Thanks. Firstly I think the Col2List will go before 'from Table1' else its giving errors. And one more question, if I have additional 'where' conditions, where would they go? I cannot add them after WHERE Col2List = '1,2,3,4,5' as the columns would not be identified because 'from Table1' is within the brackets.

Comment: Why `LISTAGG`? OP is not looking for string aggregation.

Comment: @LalitKumarB ListAgg used for aggregate values grouped by Col2. It use aggregated value in where statement later.

Comment: @hkutluay You are missing the point. there are many complicated ways of achieving it. But, what is the point in using `LISTAGG` and the delimiter etc. when all you need is a window function to return ordered set of rows from each group. `LISTAGG` is useful for string aggregation. In OP's case he would expect single values and not a delimited-list.

Comment: @LalitKumarB query returns set of rows, not delimited string. ListAgg using on filtering rows. There should be thousand other alternatives  to achieve this, but this is the way that i use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below

```
SELECT COL1
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY COL1
    HAVING 
    COUNT(COL1)=5
    AND 
    SUM(
    (CASE WHEN COL2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
    +
    (CASE WHEN COL2=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
    +
    (CASE WHEN COL2=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
    +
    (CASE WHEN COL2=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
    +
    (CASE WHEN COL2=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END))=5
```